# Auto confirm eject usb device using powershell command

Tags: command-line, usb, powershell, window

I have to use this PowerShell command to eject USB drive

```
$driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("E:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

Whenever I do Windows always ask me to confirm, How can I get it to force eject or auto confirm using this command? I have explored some suggestions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753702/automatic-confirmation-of-deletion-in-powershell) but none seem to work with this particular command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS, or PoSH version you are using, yet that may be moot based on your code post.

The difference between what you are doing and the pointer you posted, is that post is about files, not hardware.

This works for me (which is virtually the same as yours) on my Win10 SCU build. Meaning, you just get an OK to remove info notification, but not a confirm.

```
($DriveLetter = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | where {$_.drivetype -eq '2'}  ).DriveLetter)
$Eject =  New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$Eject.NameSpace(17).ParseName($DriveLetter).InvokeVerb(“Eject”)
```

In Explorer, you'll note it still shows the drive, minus any info on it, so, safe to remove.

Comment: Am on Windows 10, when the command is run, a dialog is displayed  with option to, Cancel( stop operation, drive remains), Continue( command executes, drive eject ). I am building an application and don't what the user to decide, I want to force the opperation to go through or some auto confirmation.